# Why does this rake task run twice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I have a main rake task `setup_a_new_set_of_snippets.rake` that I call, that then calls other tasks. So the main one looks like this:

```
load './lib/tasks/fetch_and_create_snippets.rake'
load './lib/tasks/generate_diffs_for_snippets.rake'
load './lib/tasks/cleanup_snippets_with_empty_diffs.rake'

desc "Setup a new set of Snippets"
task :setup_a_new_set_of_snippets, [:repo, :path, :entry_id, :framework_id, :method_name] => :environment do |task, args|
  repo = args[:repo]
  path = args[:path]
  entry_id = args[:entry_id]
  framework_id = args[:framework_id]
  method_name = args[:method_name]
  Rake::Task["fetch_and_create_snippets"].invoke(repo,path,entry_id,framework_id,method_name)
  Rake::Task["generate_diffs_for_snippets"].invoke
  Rake::Task["cleanup_snippets_with_empty_diffs"].invoke(framework_id)
end
```

For some reason, the `fetch_and_create_snippets` rake which is run like this: `Rake::Task["fetch_and_create_snippets"].invoke(repo,path,entry_id,framework_id,method_name)` seems to be run twice.

Here is that task - `fetch_and_create_snippets.rake`:

```
desc 'Fetch and Create Snippets from Github'

task :fetch_and_create_snippets, [:repo, :path, :entry_id, :framework_id, :method_name] => :environment do |task, args|
  repo = args[:repo]
  path = args[:path]
  entry_id = args[:entry_id]
  framework_id = args[:framework_id]
  method_name = args[:method_name]
  client = Octokit.client
  commits = GetCommits.new(repo, path).all
  commits_count = commits.count
  commits.each_with_index do |commit, index|
    content = client.contents(repo, path: path, ref: commit.sha)
    if Snippet.exists?(gh_sha: content.sha)
      puts "#{index}/#{commits_count} - EXISTS - #{commit.commit.author.email} - #{content.sha}".blue
    elsif commit.author.nil?
      puts "#{index}/#{commits_count} - NO AUTHOR - #{commit.commit.author.email} - #{content.sha}".magenta
    else
      create_snippet = CreateSnippet.new(repo, path, entry_id, framework_id, commit, method_name)
      if create_snippet
        puts "#{index}/#{commits_count} - #{commit.author.login} - #{commit.sha} SUCCESSFULLY CREATED".green
      else
        puts "#{index}/#{commits_count} - #{commit.author.login} - #{commit.sha} - NOT SUCCESSFULLY CREATED - #{create_snippet.errors}".red
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This is what the output to the console looks like:

First batch of successfully run events from the first run of `fetch_and_create_snippets`:

```
783/786 - dhh - ac3c8a54f83418b5cac4b093fc1bae29f59f3a1f SUCCESSFULLY CREATED
Snippet ID: 2974 SUCCESSFULLY SANITIZED
784/786 - dhh - 7022dd9c05064ef914f8836fb5e8b2d2ee3c02ed SUCCESSFULLY CREATED
Snippet ID: 2975 SUCCESSFULLY SANITIZED
785/786 - dhh - db045dbbf60b53dbe013ef25554fd013baf88134 SUCCESSFULLY CREATED
```

Then it re-runs it and shows the `EXISTS` output, which only outputs once the Snippet exists.

```
0/786 - EXISTS - acme@test.com - c91b5d3fe3d263963eb3f9ef2ec0dc0074951064
1/786 - EXISTS - acme@test.com - 3729e22e6423348aa9282cd17b49c09793ca3a6f
2/786 - EXISTS - acme@test.com - ec9b073c185dcef26bd3293ac124fee8285de103
3/786 - EXISTS - acme@test.com - 5a973fa8019962133449c073c4e8b5cf2ce8fb36
4/786 - EXISTS - acme@test.com - fe440fccc7398d2cd0b4f04f700c62cc76ba2b0a
5/786 - EXISTS - acme@test.com - 2fbecb7d0447b70b30b71addfbc97608690b4106
6/786 - EXISTS - acme@test.com - 77d17fc9757bcbbc63267c2e408b4dbe8ab5d930
7/786 - EXISTS - acme@test.com - ef35d80523fd066ae1d836658ef840dd0da93849
8/786 - EXISTS - acme@test.com - e13fe33b857c7f608590bf80030f8c837a15faea
9/786 - EXISTS - acme@test.com - 03c8b4c97be4ffaf1f84daf657915d8953219476
```

And that runs through the same batch it did the first time.

What could be causing this double run?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to remove `load` methods.
In Rails project all `*.rake` files inside of `lib/tasks` directory are automatically loaded. So all those tasks would be available without extra `load`.

In your `Rakefile` you can see initially generated comment like

> Add your own tasks in files placed in lib/tasks ending in .rake,
>   for example lib/tasks/capistrano.rake, and they will automatically be available to Rake.

I have created simple `.rake` files.

`# lib/tasks/foo.rake`

```
desc 'foo task'
task :foo do
  puts 'call foo task'
end
```

`# lib/tasks/bar.rake`

```
desc 'bar task'
task :bar do
  puts 'call bar task'
  Rake::Task['foo'].invoke
end
```

It works fine like this. The output is

```
# => call bar task
# => call foo task
```

But if I add `load` in `bar.rake`

```
load './lib/tasks/foo.rake'
desc 'bar task'
task :bar do
  puts 'call bar task'
  Rake::Task['foo'].invoke
end
```

`foo` task will be called twice.

```
# => call bar task
# => call foo task
# => call foo task
```

Comment: Thanks. In my case I had to remove the  `app.add_import 'lib/tasks/db.rake'` and not the `app.load_rakefile`.